# Using column-count, how do I style JUST the 2nd column

Tags: html, css

Using columns, I've split my paragraph of text, but due to a background graphic, I have a need to the 2nd column to be skinnier than the first. This isn't for one place in the site, I need it for 30+ pages, so a single fix won't work.

```
<p class="col-2"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

I have CSS declared

```
.col-2 { 
   column-count: 2;
   column-gap: 10px;
   column-rule: 1px solid lightblue;
}
```

Is there a way to set `column-rule [Nth]: width: 360px;` or CSS to that effect?

---

Incase there is no fix, The Pages are typically 800px wide and have a graphical background with a split down the middle. But the right side graphic interferes with the text, so I need the right column to be 360px and the left column to be 385px, with a left margin 10px, and a right margin of 35px.

Sometimes Images Occur in the text block, but I can set them to width 100% to fit what ever the column width is.

Any other clever way to do it? I might have 10 paragraphs of varied heights in those columns, so its not as simple as setting the right margin of the inner `<p>` of the 2nd set, I don't know which paragraph will be on the left / right.  [image: Example Image]

EDIT: Added the image. the right graphic makes it difficult to read any text going over it. but the 'column split' graphic is centre to the whole page (excuse my 'paint' example)

Comment: In a real-life case does the 25px width difference make material difference to the text layout? It's only a few characters' width. i.e. what does it look like if both columns are 360px?

Comment: You can't. A CSS column is not an html element and so cannot be selected (and thus styled) by CSS

Comment: @A.Haworth, The Page Graphic behind makes the text unreadable at the last 20-30px, the client wants the text to stop short but only on that edge. but the column gap must be mid page.  If both are 360, the left gap would waste realestate. Often the left column has the graphic (the first element in the column)

Comment: You won’t be able to do this with just column count. Could you perhaps show an example of what is required? I note that the dimensions are fixed, but is there any requirement for a responsive solution?

Comment: Added image example, My attempt so far, is to count the lines of the text, check if it enters the 2nd column, and apply a class with a right padding, but I hit issues when images exist in the columns, and the text floats around the images, I can't seem to find anyway to understand if the text has entered the 2nd column or not.

Comment: Can't see any way to do this with CSS. With JS it will be fiddly, and you speak of not knowing which column a paragraph might be in, but you haven't mentioned a requirement of not splitting a paragraph across two columns - is there this restriction?

Comment: Ahh yes, I've forced a paragraph to sit in either column for the moment for testing, It might become an issue for the client to make a decision on, so I think I'd rather have an answer for both alternatives. 

I'm looking into putting a right floated invisible box in the bottom right, so all text becomes forced left, unsure how to set its height as the height is also not fixed. Will test after I get some feedback.. P.S. thanks for the help. Have upvoted for your comments